# xrdp not listening on port 3389

Tags: networking, xserver, xrdp, azure

```
$ sudo netstat -plnt | grep rdp

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      83971/xrdp-sesman
```

As you can see xrdp is not listening on port 3389.

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog

May  3 04:19:36 vmName systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
May  3 04:19:36 vmName systemd[1]: Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
May  3 04:19:37 vmName systemd[1]: Reloading.
May  3 04:19:37 vmName systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
May  3 04:19:37 vmName systemd[1]: Reloading.
May  3 04:19:37 vmName systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
May  3 04:19:37 vmName systemd[1]: Reloading.
May  3 04:19:37 vmName systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
May  3 04:24:08 vmName start_jupyterhub.sh[2210]: 04:24:08.613 [ConfigProxy] #033[32minfo#033[39m: 200 GET /api/routes
May  3 04:24:08 vmName start_jupyterhub.sh[2210]: [I 2020-05-03 04:24:08.613 JupyterHub proxy:319] Checking routes
May  3 04:29:08 vmName start_jupyterhub.sh[2210]: 04:29:08.613 [ConfigProxy] #033[32minfo#033[39m: 200 GET /api/routes
May  3 04:29:08 vmName start_jupyterhub.sh[2210]: [I 2020-05-03 04:29:08.613 JupyterHub proxy:319] Checking routes

$ telnet PUBLIC_IP 3389

Trying PUBLIC_IP...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

$ sudo systemctl status xrdp
● xrdp.service - LSB: Start xrdp and sesman daemons
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/xrdp; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-05-03 04:05:37 UTC; 14min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
   CGroup: /system.slice/xrdp.service
           └─83971 /usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman

May 03 04:05:37 vmName systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start xrdp and sesman daemons..
May 03 04:05:37 vmName xrdp[83956]:  * Starting Remote Desktop Protocol server
May 03 04:05:37 vmName xrdp[83956]:    ...done.
May 03 04:05:37 vmName systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start xrdp and sesman daemons.
```

I am trying to make an rdp connection to my linux vm on azure cloud. I am able to connect through ssh as you can see above. The NSG(firewall) is allowing this port, but the rdp is not listening to this port.

Here is some part of the output of:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 3853
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 3853
...
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ldap
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 3389
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 3389
...
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ldap
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ldap
...
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 3853

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Please show your `xrdp.ini`. Make sure `use_vsock` is set to `false`.